# Getting an error on Contact matching rules when using an Account Name

Tags: duplicate-management, management

I am having a problem with my matching rules. I want to create a rule against a Contact with the criteria of Account Name with Fuzzy matching (see attached) but I keep getting an error stating: 
Error: We can't save this matching rule because it uses the Account lookup field Account Name without other Contact fields, which returns poor match results and inhibits performance. Please add at least one Contact field to the rule or modify the filter logic so the rule isn't matching on just Account Name.

But I don't know what this means as I am new to using this. Can anyone advise on how I can use the Account Name in this rule?

Thanks
Show More[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might have something to do with your filter logic. You currently have all OR's which means that you are potentially asking the platform to check just the Company Name, which is not efficient.

Try replacing your filter logic with:
`( 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 ) AND 7`